# Escape character twice, java and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, liferay

I want to get the ID of a textbox in JSF to bind a keyup event with jQuery.

I have `$('#A3023\\:formId\\:textboxId').live('keyup', function(){...});` in javascript code and it work fine. But i must call JavaScript at server side.

So,  I try with `$('#A3023\\\\:formId\\\\:textboxId')`
double escape for `\`, but it does not work.

I'm using liferay to call the JavaScript

```
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), 'script code');
```

I have some test with `alert()`. It still works, but not with any ID.
Is there any  suggest for me please?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript `\` is an escape character as well. So by putting double backslashes in the string of your jQuery selector, you are really simply including a literal single backslash character -- which jQuery then interprets somehow as an internal escape character for the colon/period.

Now since the `\` character is also the Java escape character, that means to generate the same string literal you need to change absolutely nothing.

i.e. passing the string `"$(\"#A3023\\:formId\\:textboxId\")"` into your server-side execute method should be sufficient.

Comment: I fail at server side script ... I use json on this javascript and put this script at client side, maybe it not great solution but it work